# Logistic-Regression: Prior correction at test time

Tags: machine-learning, logistic, python, scikit-learn

Using sklean.linear_model.LogisticRegression for a binary classification problem. My classes are unbalanced. The positive class comprises about 20% of the training set. When fitting the model I use:

```
logreg = LogisticRegression(class_weight="auto")
logreg.fit(X_trn,y_trn)
```

which lets sklearn give greater weight to the infrequent positive class during training. But now I want to re-balance the class_weights for test time. My first intuition is to adjust the logreg.intercept_ member of fitted model. Would this be the correct approach?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For any distribution with over binary variable $C$ and continuous variable $x$:
\begin{align}
p(C_1|x) &= \frac{p(x|C_1)p(C_1)}{p(x)}\\
&= \frac{p(x|C_1)p(C_1)}{p(x|C_1)p(C_1) + p(x|C_2)p(C_2)}\\
&= \frac{1}{1 + \frac{p(x|C_2)p(C_2)}{p(x|C_1)p(C_1)}}\\
&= \frac{1}{1 + \exp\left(\ln\frac{p(x|C_2)p(C_2)}{p(x|C_1)p(C_1)}\right)}\\
&= \frac{1}{1 + \exp\left(-\ln\frac{p(x|C_1)p(C_1)}{p(x|C_2)p(C_2)}\right)}\\
&= \frac{1}{1 + \exp\left(-w^Tx + b\right)},
\end{align}
where we define $C_1$ as the event where $C=1$ and $C_2$ as the event where $C=0$. Notice this is the typical hypothesis assumed during binary logistic regression. From the above, we have that
\begin{equation}
w^Tx + b = \ln\frac{p(x|C_1)p(C_1)}{p(x|C_2)p(C_2)}= \ln\frac{p(x|C_1)}{p(x|C_2)} + \ln\frac{p(C_1)}{p(C_2)}.
\end{equation}
If, during training, we balance the dataset or weigh the examples inversely to their class prior probabilities, we effectively have that $p(C_1) = p(C_2)$, then the above becomes
\begin{equation}
w^Tx + b = \ln\frac{p(x|C_1)}{p(x|C_2)}.
\end{equation}
The parameters $w$ and $b$ are therefore estimated under the assumption that the class prior probabilities are balanced or equal. We can re-introduce the prior log odds:
\begin{align}
w^Tx + b + \ln\frac{p(C_1)}{p(C_2)} &= \ln\frac{p(x|C_1)}{p(x|C_2)}+\ln\frac{p(C_1)}{p(C_2)}\\
w^Tx + b' &= \ln\frac{p(x|C_1)}{p(x|C_2)}+\ln\frac{p(C_1)}{p(C_2)},
\end{align}
where $b' = b + \ln\frac{p(C_1)}{p(C_2)}$. So by a simple adjustment to the bias term, we can re-introduce unbalanced priors in the test/application setting. A similar argument holds for the case of multi-class logistic regression.